# Halstead Metrics : Display list of operators and operands from code using C++

Tags: c++

I'm really new to `C++`, I've found this piece of code on GitHub, this code calculate the [Halstead Metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halstead_complexity_measures) and it's works very well, I'm trying to make it display the **operators** and **operands** like this, each operator and operands display with its occurrences :

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <climits>

#define ll long long
#define pb push_back

#define inf INT_MAX
#define ninf INT_MIN

#define MAXL 100001

#define fo(i,a,b)                   for(int i=a;i<b;i++)
#define foreach(v, c)               for( typeof( (c).begin()) v = (c).begin();  v != (c).end(); ++v)
#define all(a)                      a.begin(), a.end()
#define in(a,b)                     ( (b).find(a) != (b).end())
#define pb                          push_back
#define fill(a,v)                    memset(a, v, sizeof a)
#define sz(a)                       ((int)(a.size()))
#define mp                          make_pair

using namespace std;

const string ops[] = {
    ";",
    ",",

    // data types
    "int",
    "float",
    "string",
    "double",
    "long",
    "long long",

    // control flow
    "if",
    "else",
    "switch",
    "case",
    "do",
    "while",
    "for",

    // encapsulation
    "(",
    "{",
    "[",

    // member access
    ".",
    "->",

    // arithmetic
    "+",
    "-",
    "*",
    "/",
    "%",
    "=",
    "++",
    "--",

    // logical
    "<",
    ">",
    "<=",
    ">=",
    "==",

    // keywords
    "break",
    "continue",
    "class",
    "struct",
    "default",
    "goto",
    "operator",
    "return"

};

set<string> operators;
map<string, int> operator_counts, operand_counts;

class redundancy_pair
{
    public:
        string f,s;
        int multiplicity;

        redundancy_pair( string a, string b, int multiplicity )
        {
            this->f = a, this->s = b, this->multiplicity = multiplicity;
        }
};

// redundancy pairs are necessary to remove matches that match multiple
// patterns for example c++ matches both '++' and '+', multiplicity is
// required to make adjustments to the count variables 
vector <redundancy_pair> redundancy_pairs;

void _popualate_redundancy_pairs()
{
    for ( set<string>::iterator i = operators.begin(); i != operators.end(); i++)
    {
        for (  set<string>::iterator j = operators.begin(); j != operators.end(); j++ )
        {
            if ( (*i) != (*j) )
            {
                // find num occurences in strings
                int num_occur = 0 , pos = 0;
                while ( (pos = (*i).find(*j, pos)) != string::npos )
                {
                    num_occur++;
                    pos += (*j).length();
                }
                if ( num_occur > 0 )
                    redundancy_pairs.push_back( redundancy_pair( *j , *i , num_occur ) );
            }
        }
    }
}


void _popualate_operators ()
{
    int size = *(&ops + 1) - ops; 
    for ( int i=0 ; i < size; i++ )
        operators.insert( ops[i] );
}

void _adjust_redundancy()
{
    for ( vector<redundancy_pair>::iterator it = redundancy_pairs.begin(); it != redundancy_pairs.end(); it++ )
    {
        // second exists
        if ( operator_counts.find( (*it).s ) != operator_counts.end())
            operator_counts[(*it).f] = operator_counts[(*it).f] - operator_counts[(*it).s]*((*it).multiplicity);
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{

    // fill the operators
    _popualate_operators();
    _popualate_redundancy_pairs();


    // we now create a regex for identifier
    regex identifier_def( "[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*" );

    // numbers defined at word boundary , important condition
    // for matching numbers is that they have to be separated by
    // word boundaries
    regex number_def( "\\b([0-9]+)\\b" );

    smatch sm;

    ifstream file( "code.txt" );
    string input;

    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        while ( getline( file, input ) )
        {
            // now check for operators in the line
            for ( set<string>::iterator op = operators.begin(); op != operators.end(); op++)
            {
                int pos = 0;
                // for every operator scan the entire line for multiple matches
                while (( pos = input.find( *op, pos )) != string::npos)
                {
                    // found an operator
                    if ( operator_counts.find( *op ) == operator_counts.end() )
                        operator_counts.insert({ *op, 1 });
                    else
                        operator_counts[*op]++;

                    pos += (*op).length();
                }
            }

            // now lets check for identifiers
            string::const_iterator pos( input.cbegin() );
            while( regex_search (pos, input.cend(), sm , identifier_def))
            {
                // check if identifier is an operator 
                if ( operators.find( sm[0] ) != operators.end() )
                {
                    pos += sm.position() + sm.length();
                    continue;
                }

                string operand = sm[0];
                // if not add to map
                if ( operand_counts.find( operand ) != operand_counts.end() )
                    operand_counts[operand]++;
                else 
                    operand_counts.insert( make_pair( operand, 1 ) );

                pos += sm.position() + sm.length();
            }
                
            // search for numbers 
            pos = input.cbegin();
            while ( regex_search( pos, input.cend(), sm, number_def  ) )
            {
                // check if identifier is an operator 
                if ( operators.find( sm[0] ) != operators.end() )
                {
                    pos += sm.position() + sm.length();
                    continue;
                }

                string operand = sm[0];
                // cout << "Operand : " << operand << endl;
                // if not add to map
                if ( operand_counts.find( operand ) != operand_counts.end() )
                    operand_counts[operand]++;
                else 
                    operand_counts.insert( make_pair( operand, 1 ) );

                pos += sm.position() + sm.length();
            }
        }

        _adjust_redundancy();
    }


    int N1=0,n1=0,n2=0,N2=0;
    for ( map<string, int>::iterator it=operator_counts.begin(); it != operator_counts.end(); it++ )
    {
        if ( (*it).second ) n1++;
        N1 += (*it).second;
    }
    
    for ( map<string, int>::iterator it=operand_counts.begin(); it != operand_counts.end(); it++ )
    {
        if( (*it).second ) n2++;
        N2 += (*it).second;
    }

    printf("n1:%d, n2:%d, N1:%d, N2:%d\n", n1, n2 , N1, N2);

    // compute the halstead metrics now 
    
    // program size defined as the sum of 
    // all operands and operators 
    int size = N1 + N2;

    // Vocabulary size -- Size of the vocabulary 
    // defined as sum of distinct operands and operators
    int vocab_size = n1+n2;
    
    // Volume - Program Volume , defined as follows:
    // Volume = size x log ( vocab_size )
    double volume = size*log2(vocab_size);
    
    // Difficulty = ( n1/2 ) x ( N2/n2 ) and level = 1/difficulty
    double difficulty = (double(n1)/2) * (double(N2)/double(n2));
    double level = (1/difficulty);
    
    // effort = volume x difficulty
    double effort = volume*difficulty;

    cout << "Size : " << size << endl;
    cout << "Vocabulary Size : " << vocab_size << endl;
    cout << "volume : " << volume << endl;
    cout << "difficulty : " << difficulty << endl;
    cout << "level : " << level << endl;
    cout << "effort : " << effort << endl;
}
```

For a beginner it's really hard to modify this code, I just want to know which part, I need to look in order to display **operators** and **operands**

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to describe the results you are currently obtaining -- and how they differ from the outcome you anticipated.